# How to set Build Profile in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have 3 different environments (Alpha, Beta and QA).

[image]

I'm trying to setup TFS Build based on environments and have to provide appropriate build profile in msbuild comment. I tried providing /p:PublishProfile="Profilename" and "ProfileName.pubxml", but nothing seems to be working.

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you able to run MSBuild command with this arguments locally?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to publish a web project from MSBuild command line. You may try the MSBuild arguments below:

```
/p:Configuration=xx /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Profilename /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```